# File upload using jquery AJAX to REST

Tags: jquery, rest, jersey, resteasy

I want to upload a file using jquery ajax. I have a REST application. This REST application is using token based authentication. On successful login it will create a token into database table. And this token is passed on every request after login. I have a filter which is checking whether the each request after login is having token or not and if request contains token then it is validated against the database entry.

What I want is to call the REST url using Jquery AJAX call which should add auth key inside header.

following is my code which is not working and inside filter it is failing.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="progress">
 <input type="file" id="file">
        <input type=button name="btn" value="Upload" id="fileUpload">
</div>
<br/>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#fileUpload", function(event) {
    console.log($('#file').val());
    var filename = $("#file").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('pubKey', 'abcd');},
        url : "http://localhost:8080/restapp/somename/getContacts",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function() { alert('Success!' ); },
        error: function() { alert('Hushhhhhhhhhhhh!' ); }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how to add data/key inside header. I searched on several blogs but nothing is working and filter is kicking out request every time.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. I am trying with stand alone html code to access REST module. My REST module need "authentication" key as a request header attribute. And without server we can not set and get the header attribute in REST module. To set request header parameter we must have html running on server so that the server will write the request header for us.